# AWS App runner - Django - migrations after deploy fails

Tags: python, django, aws-app-runner

AS part of the development model changes are made and prepared with makemigrations. When deploying this code to another instance (via Git) the migrations need to be run on the database of the instance.
I have configured the apprunner.yaml file as:

```
['''version: 1.0
runtime: python3
build:
  commands:
    build:
      - pip install -r requirements/production.txt
    post-build:
      - source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
      - python manage.py migrate
      - deactivate
run:
  runtime-version: 3.8.16
  command: sh startup.sh
  network:
    port: 8000''']
```

I've also tried it without the 'post-build' section. startup.sh contains:
'''#!/bin/bash
gunicorn config.wsgi:application'''
also tried a version of the startup.sh with below - also fails

'''#!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate && gunicorn config.wsgi:application'''
Log:

```
12-01-2023 10:05:40 AM [AppRunner] Reading apprunner.yaml config 

file.
12-01-2023 10:05:40 AM [AppRunner] Successfully Validate configuration file.
12-01-2023 10:05:42 AM [AppRunner] Starting source code build.
12-01-2023 10:09:00 AM [AppRunner] Service update failed. For details, see service logs.
```

I've tried variants of the `yaml` file as mentioned, one without the post-build, a post-build with on,y the Python... line,
variants of the startup.sh file as above.

I've also tried using just the build settings it falls back on to change the start command from `gunicorn` `config.wsgi:application` to Python `manage.py` migrate && `gunicorn` `config.wsgi:application`.
All just fails and rolls back.

Comment: What details did you find in the service logs?

Comment: I can't even find the so-called service logs, nor any direction from the documentation on it. Any suggestions?